# I need to pass a Pandas Dataframe to a class and use the constructor to initialize class attributes using the data from the Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pytest

I am creating a class that has two constructors. One that can accept all attributes as input and one that accepts a Pandas Dataframe as input and then creates an object using the data from the dataframe as inputs for the first constructor. This code is shown below with some variable names changed.

```
class Platform:
    NAMES = ['Blah', 'Blah 2']
        
    def __init__(self, PlatformName, Mishaps, Hours, ProbBlah, ShelterFactor, ParachuteFactor, WingSpan, Buffer, Length):
        if PlatformName not in Platform.NAMES:
            raise ValueError(f'unknown PlatformName [{PlatformName}]')
        else:
            self.PlatformName = PlatformName
            self.Mishaps = Mishaps
            self.Hours = Hours
            self.ProbBlah = ProbBlah
            self.ShelterFactor = ShelterFactor
            self.ParachuteFactor = ParachuteFactor
            self.WingSpan = WingSpan
            self.Buffer = Buffer
            self.Length = Length
    
    def __init__(self, df):
        Platform(df.loc[0,'PlatformName'], df.loc[0,'Mishaps'],             
        df.loc[0,'Hours'], df.loc[0,'ProbBlah'], 
        df.loc[0,'ShelterFactor'], df.loc[0,'ParachuteFactor'], 
        df.loc[0,'WingSpan'], df.loc[0,'Buffer'], df.loc[0,'Length'])`
```

I am trying to set up some automated tests through PyTest and I am getting an error when testing this code.

```
TypeError: Platform.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 10 were given

Blah\Platform.py:21: TypeError
```

The test code is as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture        
def Blah_Dataframe():
    data = {'PlatformName':['Blah'], 'Mishaps':[20], 'Hours':[631403.9], 'ProbBlah':[1], 'ShelterFactor':[0.75], 'ParachuteFactor':[5], 'WingSpan':[56], 'Buffer':[1], 'Length':[28]}
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return data
    
def test_platform_name_Blah(Blah_Dataframe):
    p = Platform(Blah_Dataframe)
```

I'm thinking I maybe set up the constructor incorrectly, but I'm not really sure here. Any thoughts or recommendations are appreciated

Comment: It looks like you defined `__init__` twice in the Platform class. Python doesn't allow this.

Comment: Unlike Java where you can have multiple constructors, then you can only have one in Python.

So in your case, it is actually the second `__init__` that will be the constructor for your class.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm coming from Java programming so I just forgot about Python only allowing one constructor.